# How to make USB audio work again? (Headphones connected to docking station connected to laptop)

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I connected an Ubuntu laptop to a docking station, and a pair of headphones to the docking station. For a while I there was no problem and I heard the sound over the headphones connected to the docking station. Now there is no audio anymore when the computer is connecting to the docking station. I do not know what changed and why it stopped working.

I tried playing with the sound settings but did not find a solution.
This is how it looks over there while playing audio:
When `Headphones - USB Audio` is selected, the sound bar is constant (one constant light blue bar). No sound on Test.

[image]

Exactly the same with `Speakers - Built-in Audio`:
[image]

`Line Out - USB Audio` seems to react to the internal microphone of the laptop (Not to the microphone of the headphones plugged in to the docking station). The dark blue bars appear when I tap on the laptop.

[image]

Any idea how to make sound go through to my headphones again<s>, or at least make it go through to my headphones when they are connected directly to the laptop while it is connected to the docking station(even that does not work)</s>?

**Edit**: I managed to get audio when connecting the headphones directly to the laptop instead of the docking station, by running
`pavucontrol` and choosing the built-in audio option.

Are there any commands I can run that would help diagnose the problem?

Comment: Try resetting your pulseaudio configuration by executing: 
``mv ~/.config/pulse/ ~/.config/pulse.old`` Then 
``systemctl --user restart pulseaudio`` and go into "Settings" on your desktop and select the desired Sound/Output Device.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, @stumblebee, unfortunately this did not work.